# Github: error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 10053 fatal

Tags: git, github

Tried with

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

still did not work out. Got same error:

```
Enumerating objects: 46108, done.
Counting objects: 100% (46108/46108), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (40948/40948), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10053
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (46107/46107), 3.07 GiB | 19.76 MiB/s, done.
Total 46107 (delta 3570), reused 46107 (delta 3570)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```